# Zero Downtime Deployments on tcServer?

Tags: java, springsource

I've been investigating using tcServer and one problem I have is the same problem I have always had with tomcat... outages when deploying applications.

SURELY there is some way to have zero downtime when deploying applications to tcServer?

Comment: even on a single machine, if you were willing to get a bit creative with your firewall/port redirections it has always been possible to have zero downtime but it was quite tricky ; )   But anyway since version 7, Tomcat supports what is called *"Parallel Deployment"* which may be exactly what you're after: http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/05/31/parallel-deployment-tomcat-7

Comment: @user988052 That is a very useful comment. You should have answered with this instead of commenting.

Comment: @Dev: ok, I did put it as an answer : )

Answer (score 2):

*(as suggested in the comments, I post this as an answer)*

Since version 7, Tomcat supports what is called "Parallel Deployment" which may be exactly what you're after.  The following blog entry talks about that feature and how it was planned for tcServer at first but was then migrated/donated to Apache to become an integral part of Tomcat:

http://tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/05/31/parallel-deployment-tomcat-7

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven/Ant, see the Tomcat 7 parallel deployment script at http://tynamo.org/Zero+downtime+deployment+to+Tomcat+7+with+Maven